# JOIN query optimization using indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The question is: How to increase the speed of this query?

```
SELECT
    c.CategoryName,
    sc.SubcategoryName,
    pm.ProductModel,
    COUNT(p.ProductID) AS ModelCount
FROM Marketing.ProductModel pm
    JOIN Marketing.Product p
        ON p.ProductModelID = pm.ProductModelID
    JOIN Marketing.Subcategory sc
        ON sc.SubcategoryID = p.SubcategoryID
    JOIN Marketing.Category c
        ON c.CategoryID = sc.CategoryID
GROUP BY c.CategoryName,
    sc.SubcategoryName,
    pm.ProductModel
HAVING COUNT(p.ProductID) > 1
```

Schema: 
[image: DATA SCEMA]

I tried creating some indexes and reorganizing the order of the JOINs. This did not increase productivity in the least. Maybe I need other indexes or a different query? 
My solution:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_Marketing_Subcategory_IDandName ON Marketing.Subcategory (CategoryID)
CREATE INDEX idx_Marketing_Product_PMID ON Marketing.Product (ProductModelID)
CREATE INDEX idx_Marketing_Product_SCID ON Marketing.Product (SubcategoryID)
        
        SELECT
            c.CategoryName,
            sc.SubcategoryName,
            pm.ProductModel,
            COUNT(p.ProductID) AS ModelCount
        FROM Marketing.Category AS c
            JOIN Marketing.Subcategory AS SC
                ON c.CategoryID = SC.CategoryID
            JOIN Marketing.Product AS P
                ON SC.SubcategoryID = p.SubcategoryID
            JOIN Marketing.ProductModel AS PM
                ON P.ProductModelID = PM.ProductModelID
        GROUP BY c.CategoryName,
            sc.SubcategoryName,
            pm.ProductModel
        HAVING COUNT(p.ProductID) > 1
```

UPD: 
Results: 
[image: Results] 
Plan with my indexes: 
[Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1cp2GpDF)

Comment: If you have `JOIN Marketing.Product p  ON p.ProductModelID = pm.ProductModelID`, then you should benefit from an index on `Product.ProductModelID` and and index on `ProductModel.ProductModelID`.  Of course, the same rule can/should be applied to the other joins....

Comment: @Luuk I added it, but it didn't help, the speed didn't increase

Comment: I can’t see any filters that can act before doing the joins and aggregation. Are any of your join conditions significant cutting down the number of rows that will need to be read for any table? If not then hash joins and scans are the way to go. It’s possible to misinterpret your screenshot as it’s partly in another language but it looks like you have a nested loop to `Marketing.Category` which could be the reason for it taking too long. If forcing that join to use a hash join improves it then investigate why your table statistics makes the query planner believe a nested loops is better

Comment: @ku4er99: `speed` is relative.... How many rows are you selecting from ? and what time is it currently taking to perform this query ? Also "increase speed" is also relative, would an increase in speed of 0.5% be acceptable ? 

Comment: Your screen shot is not really useful and it looks like you're using a very out-of-date version of SSMS. Add the actual execution plan using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: @Luuk average request rate 140 ms. There are 504 rows in the Product table.

Comment: @Stu [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1cp2GpDF) Good tool, thanks

Comment: @AndrewSayer here's a clear and readable plan: [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1cp2GpDF)

Comment: @ku4er99 was that plan taken from the same system as where the problem occurs? It says that it took 4ms and has two nested loops rather than the one I saw in the screenshot. Did you see my previous question about filtering? It can’t be seen from the plan you’ve shared unfortunately. That said, hash joins and scans are probably the way to go, you almost definitely don’t need a covering index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has a cost of 0.12 which is trivial, as is the number of rows, it executes in microseconds, row esitmates are also reasonably close so it's not clear what the problem is you are trying to solve.

Looking at the execution plan there is a key lookup for `ProductModelId` with an estimated cost of 44% of the query, so you could eliminate this with a *covering index* by including the column in the index *Product.idx_Marketing_Product_SCID*

```
Create index idx_Marketing_Product_SCID on Marketing.Product (SubcategoryID)
include (ProductModelId) with(drop_existing=on)
```

Comment: I think that's enough. Thank you.